# Flutter, dart. How to add key and value to a map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

Im kind of new to dart. Im trying to add values that I can pass to another class. I am using the onTap function and have created one empty map and one counter variable (to be able to pass how many taps). The user should tap on the screen on an image and an image and a int should be stored in the map. It seems like the key is overwritten all the time though and only the increment are working (how many taps). I hope you guys can interpret this and give an advice!

This is my code:

```
final String image;
Map<String, int> _passover = {};
final int tapsCount = 1;


              onTap: () {
                if (_passover.containsKey(image)) {
               
                  _passover.update(image, (tapsCount) => tapsCount + 1);
                } else {
                  
                  _passover.putIfAbsent(image, () => tapsCount);
                  
                }
                //Should print all keys or all values

                print(_passover.entries);
                
              },
              
            ),
```

And this is the output when clicking on different pictures. As you can see only one key is stored and the previous is overwritten or something?

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
Reloaded 1 of 561 libraries in 255ms.
I/flutter ( 8812): (MapEntry(images/redOnion.png: 1))
I/flutter ( 8812): (MapEntry(images/milkRed.png: 1))
I/flutter ( 8812): (MapEntry(images/milkBlue.png: 1))
I/flutter ( 8812): (MapEntry(images/milkBlue.png: 2))
I/flutter ( 8812): (MapEntry(images/milkGreen.png: 1))
I/flutter ( 8812): (MapEntry(images/milkGreen.png: 2))
I/flutter ( 8812): (MapEntry(images/milkRed.png: 1))
I/flutter ( 8812): (MapEntry(images/potatoes.png: 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you are using stateless widget for this purpose. when you want data to be changed based on user interactions, you should use a stateful widget, otherwise data will be overwritten every time. so this code using a stateful widget will be something like this:

```
onTap: () {
        if (_passover.containsKey(image)) {
            setState(() {
                _passover.update(image, (tapsCount) => tapsCount + 1);

                        });
        } else {
            setState(() {
          _passover.putIfAbsent(image, () => tapsCount);

                    });
          
        }
        //Should print all keys or all values

        print(_passover.entries);
        
      },
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. I can see that if I change it into a stateful I also have to implement a crateState method. I will read up on this.

Comment: I converted the stateless to a stateful and implemented the setstate. I also created a method of the code that was in onTap that I call on inside onTap. But unfortunatly it is the same output. That is only one key is saved in the map what I can se.  Its also a little strange that the incremented value seems to work but the map is not growing and as before one value is outputed at a time: 
I/flutter (11597): (MapEntry(images/redOnion.png: 3))
I/flutter (11597): (MapEntry(images/redOnion.png: 4))
I/flutter (11597): (MapEntry(images/potatoes.png: 1))

Comment: try printing ( print(_passover); ) instead of entries and see values

Comment: It's the same. nNo more keys than one are showing but the int is incrementing.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned from the beggining that I have extracted the widget from my main code (it became a steteless) but I have as mentioned above turned it into a stateful with setstate. Then I call on the widget and insert an image from main like this:ImageCircle(image: 'images/milkBlue.png'),
                ImageCircle(image: 'images/milkRed.png'),

Comment: make the declaration of map final and see the results final Map<String, int> _passover = {};

Comment: No, that is not working either unfortunatly. The same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this myself and the problem was that I did not use a global variable. But when I use a global variable it works fine and the map stores everything as it should and its not written over. Thank you Benjyamin for your suggestions to fix my code!